# Product measure and splitting integral

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, A, \mu), (Y, B, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite and $f \in \mathcal L^1 (\mu)$, $g \in \mathcal L^1 (\nu)$. I want to show that

1. $fg \in \mathcal L^1 (\mu \otimes \nu)$
2. $\int fg \ d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int f \ d\mu \int g \ d\nu.$

My attempt on part 1 is since $f \in \mathcal L^1 (\mu)$ and $g \in \mathcal L^1 (\nu)$, so

$$\int |f| \ d\mu \lt \infty \text{ and } \int |g| \ d\nu \lt \infty$$

and

$$\int |f| \ d\mu  \int |g| \ d\nu \lt \infty$$

$$\iint |fg| \ d\mu d\nu \lt \infty $$

Hence $fg \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu \otimes \nu)$

For part 2 I have written $f$ and $g$ in the form of simple functions and shown that $\int fg \ d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int f \ d\mu \int g \ d\nu.$ But my question is, don't simple functions only work for positive function, my $f$ and $g$ are general through.

Comment: Write $f=f^+-f^-$ (and $g=g^+-g^-$) where $f^+$ and $f^-$ denote the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively. Using the linearity of the integral, you get the result for general $f$,$g$ if you know  that the claim holds for non-negative $f,g$.